# Swift: Delegate is nil

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm trying to create an `AppCoordinator` which holds the different `ViewControllers` in my app:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let appCoordinator = AppCoordinator()
    window?.rootViewController = appCoordinator.initialTabBarController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
// ...


import SnapKit

class AppCoordinator {

    private let initialTabController = TabBarController()
    private let cars = CarProvider.sharedInstance.getCars()

    init() {
        var viewControllers = [ViewController]()
        viewControllers.append(carListViewController())

        initialTabController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
    }

    private func carListViewController() -> CarListViewController {
        let controller = CarListViewController(cars: cars)
        print(self)
        controller.delegate = self
        return controller
    }
}

// MARK: - CarListViewControlerDelegate
extension AppCoordinator: CarListViewControlerDelegate {
    func didPullToRefresh() {
        print("Did pull")
    }
}
```

My `CarListViewController` looks like this:

```
import UIKit

protocol CarListViewControlerDelegate: class {
    func didPullToRefresh()
}

class CarListViewController: ViewController {

    weak var delegate: CarListViewControlerDelegate?

    // MARK: Interface Properties
    private let tableView = TableView()
    private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    private var cars: [Car]?

    // MARK: Initializers
    init(cars: [Car]) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.cars = cars
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

// MARK: - Actions
extension CarListViewController {

    @objc private func refresh() {
        delegate?.didPullToRefresh()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

My refresh method gets called when I pull to refresh in my `UITableView`, but the protocol method `didPullToRefresh` doesn't. When I check on the delegate, it's value is `nil`.

Comment: Can you show how you instantiate **AppCoordinator** ??

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a strong reference so  make it an instance var inside `AppDelegate`

```
let appCoordinator = AppCoordinator()
```

**OR**

```
var appCoordinator:AppCoordinator! 

self.appCoordinator = AppCoordinator()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sh_Khan said you need a strong reference. You should change the way you set the delegate for created `CarListViewController`.

I've changed your code as below. let me know if the problem solved.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let appCoordinator = AppCoordinator()
    window?.rootViewController = appCoordinator.initialTabBarController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
// ...


import SnapKit

class AppCoordinator {

    private let initialTabController = TabBarController()
    private let cars = CarProvider.sharedInstance.getCars()
    var controller = CarListViewController!

    init() {
        var viewControllers = [ViewController]()
        let carListVC = CarListViewController(cars: cars)

        self.controller = carListVC
        self.controller.delegate = self

        viewControllers.append(self.controller)

        initialTabController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
    }
}

// MARK: - CarListViewControlerDelegate
extension AppCoordinator: CarListViewControlerDelegate {
    func didPullToRefresh() {
        print("Did pull")
    }
}
```